# Return And Pass Array to function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to return an array and pass it to a different function:

```
    int* getBasicArray(){
        int amountArray[5];
        amountArray[0]=1;

        return amountArray;
    }
    void printArray(int (*amountArray)){
        cout <<amountArray[0]<<endl;
    }
int main() 
{
    int* test=getBasicArray();
    cout <<test[0]<<endl; //Prints 1
    printArray(test); //Prints 19354128
```

Somehow my array is getting messed up when I try and pass it to a simple printing function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These parantheses around `*amountArray` are kind of weird.

Comment: The problem is the `printArray` nothing wrong with `getBasicArray`, this is similar http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_return_arrays_from_functions.htm just make `int` into `static int`

Comment: @SSpoke there is definitely a big problem with `getBasicArray`.

Comment: std::cout in `printArray` works fine, is just prints the address of a pointer.

Comment: @SSpoke ..nothing wrong except for function returns a pointer to a local variable

Comment: @mexus but i'm pretty sure he wants them both to return 1 not some huge number!.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331437/passing-struct-to-functions

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to an array which is a local variable of the `getBasicArray` function. It is a dangling pointer, and de-referencing it is undefined behaviour. You could try returning an `std::array` or an `std::vector` instead. This is an example using `std::array`:

```
std::array<int,5> getBasicArray()
{
    std::array<int, 5> amountArray;
    amountArray[0]=1;
    return amountArray;
}
```

Next, modify your function accordingly. This is the `std::array` version:

```
template <size_t N>
void printArray(const std::array<int,N>& amountArray)){
    std::cout << amountArray[0] << std::endl;
}
```

and this is the `std::vector` one:

```
void printArray(const std::vector<int>& amountArray)){
    std::cout << amountArray[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a pointer to a temporary local object which is destroying right after exiting the function.

Why don't you try `std::vector` and get rid of pointers?

```
std::vector<int> getBasicArray()
{
   std::vector<int> amountArray(5);
   amountArray[0]=1;

   return amountArray;
}

void printArray(const std::vector<int> &arr)
{
   for (auto &x : arr)
        cout << x <<endl;
}

int main() 
{
    auto test = getBasicArray(); // std::vector<int> test =  getBasicArray();

    cout <<test[0]<<endl;

    printArray(test); 
}
```

Comment: _auto_ keyword (and the whole foreach-style) may be a bit confusing if topic starter is not familiar with c++11 (and something makes me feel that way)

Comment: @mexus: I don't agree with you, `auto` is one of the simplest stuff when learning C++. BTW, I commented a _non-auto_ way.

Comment: @mexus FWIW, I think it is no longer necessary to assume c++03 and then teach c++11 *on top* of that. If OP needs c++03 solutions, they should specify this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`getBasicArray` is not well behaved, the pointer will point garbage once it returns.
If you truly want to allocate an array you would have to do so using `operator new[]`.

```
int* getBasicArray() {
    return new int[5];
}
```

Note tho that you are no longer using automatic storage, and you must call delete when you wish you free the memory used.

Simplest solution is, just do not use raw arrays. They have inherent problems such as, you can't get the number of elements in an array, they decay easily, etc.

Alternatives are `std::vector` and `std::array`.
Use the latter when you know the size of the array at compile time, the former when you know the size at runtime.

In this case, you know the size at compile time so use std::array.

```
std::array<int, 5> get_basic_array()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
    arr[0] = 1;

    return arr;
}
```